# Should we merge the tag [idiomatic] into [idioms]?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Reading the description of these two tags [idiomatic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/idiomatic) and [idioms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/idioms), it seems that they are both covering the same material.

I don't have a strong preference for either one, and they both have over 300 questions tagged each, so it would probably be best to create a tag synonym.

Note, however, I am not able to initiate that process due to a lack of reputation on the site.

**Edit** - *I have now proposed the tag synonym. Those with sufficient tag reputation may vote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/idioms/synonyms)*

Comment: Should they exist at all? They seem kind of meta.

Comment: @Andrew I have noticed sometimes it is used as an excuse to ask for an open-ended, opinion-based code review. Just attaching the phrase "what is the idiomatic way" allows you to post a question that might otherwise be off-topic and/or too subjective. Then it devolves into: show me every conceivable way to do this thing that already had a reasonable answer.

Comment: I didn't vote, but you should be aware that votes on Meta work a little differently - they can be (and usually are) used to express approval or disapproval of the idea, rather than saying anything about the quality of the question. So a downvote here is kind of a "no" vote for the proposal, and folks who voted "no" on this *particular* question probably think neither tag belongs on SO at all, and are thus not worth merging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [idioms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/idioms) ← [idiomatic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/idiomatic)

The above merge and synonymization is now complete. I chose fairly arbitrarily which tag to make the primary one. I think it makes more sense to have a noun as the name of a tag, rather than a verb.

Both tags had essentially the same wiki and were, as you mentioned, being used in identical ways.

Probably, at some point, this tag should be cleaned up, as it's not the type of tag that we consider to be useful in categorizing questions (see ["The Death of Meta Tags"](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/)). But there was no reason not to merge these identically-used tags at this point. The clean-up can be saved for later, when nobody has anything better to do.