# Approving synonyms for non-top tags

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

I suggested a tag synonym a couple of days ago for [stata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stata).

However, I then realized that there are really only three (!) active users (including me) that satisfy the (overall and tag-specific) reputation requirements for voting and hence approval. There are also a few occasional contributors to the tag, but they have not answered any questions in a long time and it looks like there isn't a direct way to contact them.

This makes it practically impossible to approve a synonym, not only for [stata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stata), but I suspect also for any *non-top* tags. I am aware of other posts on Meta Stack Overflow discussing the difficulty of approving tag synonyms in general. But for *top* tags anyone can simply ask on here for people to vote for a suggestion if they agree with it.

I was thus wondering, are there any procedures for tag synonym approval when 
there are not enough users with the required reputation to vote for suggestions?

Comment: There is only one question with that tag.  The tag was created when you edited that question.  What was the point of that?  Just remove the tag again and you won't have a problem to solve.

Comment: @Hans In short, the tag was created because the question was referring to the Stata's other (matrix) programming language. There is an important distinction between the two Stata languages. But there are only a handful of questions relating to `mata` specifically, which is more specialized so i would like any such future questions to be re-mapped to the Stata tag.

Comment: Irrespective of this particular instance, i think it would be helpful for everyone to know if there are procedures in place for dealing with situations like this one?

Comment: Small tag communities just don't need a lot of tags to find each other.  One is enough, [stata] looks like the correct one when you don't mata without stata :)  The tag creation procedure is [documented here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-it-appropriate-to-create-a-tag-and-how-does-it-work)

Comment: @Hans it is Stata not Strata :) I agree, i only created a new tag because i could not suggest `mata` as a synonym otherwise. But i think it is important future questions relating to `mata` to be categorized under the stata tag properly.

Comment: Well, they already are and users have to pick [stata] because there is no [mata].  So there is no problem that needs to be solved.  Unless you create the problem.

Comment: @Hans let's not distract readers from the main point of my question, which is about the process itself :)

Comment: If it is about the process, see MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-and-merged-tags-how-do-they-work, also there is a whole tag here one meta about synonym requests: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/synonym-request

Comment: @rene thank you, the post is informative but does not really answer my question. Or perhaps it does indirectly, in the sense that there is no way of approving tag synonyms in smaller communities where there are not enough users with sufficient reputation.

Comment: Related: [Does the tag synonym suggestion system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127459) (contains some suggested fixes)

Comment: @Dukeling thank you, that is helpful indeed. I suppose the only real solution in this case, is for a moderator to accept the synonym in question.

Comment: If you synonymize a tag, that tag gets replaced by its parent. So Hans's comment is pretty on the nose.

Comment: Here are a couple of more obvious ones: assertions -> assertion. And [idiomatic -> idioms](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344859/should-we-merge-the-tag-idiomatic-into-idioms).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Ask moderators to approve the tag synonym.

As the answer by user @josliber (*Tag Synonym Statistics at Top Network Sites*) in the question [Does the tag synonym suggestion system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127459/does-the-tag-synonym-suggestion-system-work) points out:

> In summary, tag synonyms do get approved by vote, though not as often as they get approved by mods. 33% of the synonyms on Stack Overflow were approved by vote, and only 3% of the synonyms on the remaining sites were approved by vote.

So this solution appears to be the ***only*** viable one, at the moment, for smaller communities where there are not enough users with sufficient reputation to vote for a tag synonym.

Comment: @pnuts You do realize that is a self-defeating attitude, don't you? It's best not to try and infect others with it.

Comment: @pnuts There is no practical chance of improvement because one random user prescribed it as fact after presenting a view through one particular micro lens... I don't buy it, and other users shouldn't be convinced that way, either.

Comment: Related: [How to gather support for tag synonyms?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312430/how-to-gather-support-for-tag-synonyms)